# Data Timestamp Android

Tags: android, csv, image-processing, timestamp

I am developing an application where i do some real time image processing. In my camera view I do the image processing inside the **onPreviewFrame** where i loop through  each pixel and then find the sum Y value of each frame. I then save this into a csv file and everything works perfect. Except, i also want to store the time elapsed between each frame in the csv along with each y-sum.

**ImageProcessing**

```
public abstract class ImageProcessing {

 public static int YUV420SPtoYSum(byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height){

    if(yuv420sp == null)
        return 0;

    int sum = 0;
    final int ii = 0;
    final int ij = 0;
    final int di = +1;
    final int dj = +1;
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0, ci = ii; i < height; ++i, ci += di) {
        for (int j = 0, cj = ij; j < width; ++j, cj += dj) {
            y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[ci * width + cj]));
            //y = y < 16 ? 16 : y;

            sum += y;
        }
    }
  return sum;
 }
}
```

**CameraView Class**

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

private static final String TAG = "CameraView";
Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
int img_Y_Avg, img_U_Avg, img_V_Avg;


public interface PreviewReadyCallback {
    void onPreviewFrame(int yAverage, int uAverage, int vAverage); // Any value you want to get
}

PreviewReadyCallback mPreviewReadyCallback = null;

public void setOnPreviewReady(PreviewReadyCallback cb) {
    mPreviewReadyCallback = cb;
}



public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    for(Camera.Size str: mSupportedPreviewSizes)
        Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR","Camera error on SurfaceCreated" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {

    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)
        return;
    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR","Camera error on SurfaceChanged" + e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        parameters.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        //parameters.setAutoExposureLock(false);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        //set fps
        parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(16000, 16000);
        //on flash
        parameters.setFlashMode(parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        //parameters.setAutoWhiteBalanceLock(true);
        parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);

        /*if (parameters.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0){ // check that metering areas are supported
            List<Camera.Area> meteringAreas = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();

            Rect areaRect1 = new Rect(-50, -50, 50, 50);    // specify an area in center of image
            meteringAreas.add(new Camera.Area(areaRect1, 1000)); // set weight to 60%
            parameters.setMeteringAreas(meteringAreas);
        }*/



        //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR","Camera error on SurfaceChanged" + e.getMessage());
    }
}



@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    if (mCamera != null){
        //mCamera.stopPreview();
        //mCamera.release();
    }

}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera){

    //check if data is null
    if (data == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    Camera.Size size = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();

    //check if size is null
    if(size == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();


    //set resolution of camera view to optimal setting
    int width = size.width;
    int height = size.height;
    Log.d("Resolution ", " "+String.valueOf(width)+" "+String.valueOf(height));

    //call ImageProcess on the data to decode YUV420SP to RGB
    img_Y_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoYSum(data, width, height);
    img_U_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoUSum(data, width, height);
    img_V_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoVSum(data, width, height);

    mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewFrame(img_Y_Avg, img_U_Avg, img_V_Avg);

}




@Override
protected  void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if(mSupportedPreviewSizes != null){
        mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        Log.d("Resolution ", " "+mPreviewSize);
    }
}


private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h){
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes){
        double ratio = (double) size.width  / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff){
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null){
        minDiff = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes){
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff){
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraView.PreviewReadyCallback {
private static Camera camera = null;
private CameraView image = null;

private LineChart bp_graph;
private static int img_Y_Avg = 0, img_U_Avg = 0, img_V_Avg = 0;
double valueY, valueU, valueV;
Handler handler;
private int readingRemaining = 600;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    bp_graph = (LineChart)findViewById(R.id.graph);


    graph_features();

    //open camera
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();

        handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        image = new CameraView(this, camera);
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(image);
        image.setOnPreviewReady(this);
    }

    //close camera button
    ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

private void graph_features(){
    bp_graph.getDescription().setEnabled(false);


    //enable touch gesture
    bp_graph.setTouchEnabled(true);

    //enable scaling
    bp_graph.setDragEnabled(true);

    //scale and drag
    bp_graph.setScaleEnabled(true);
    bp_graph.setDrawGridBackground(false);

    //enable pinch zoom in
    bp_graph.setPinchZoom(true);

    //alternative background color
    bp_graph.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

    //work on data
    LineData lineData = new LineData();
    lineData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    //add data to line chart
    bp_graph.setData(lineData);

    //animate
    bp_graph.animateX(600);

    Legend legend = bp_graph.getLegend();

    //custom legend
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    XAxis x1 = bp_graph.getXAxis();
    x1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    x1.setDrawGridLines(false);
    x1.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    x1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

    YAxis y1 = bp_graph.getAxisLeft();
    y1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


    y1.setAxisMaximum(5000000);
    y1.setAxisMinimum(100000);
    y1.setDrawGridLines(true);
    //y1.setInverted(true);

    YAxis y2 = bp_graph.getAxisRight();
    y2.setEnabled(false);
}


//method to create set
  private ILineDataSet createSet() {
      LineDataSet set = new LineDataSet(null, "PPG");

      set.setLineWidth(1.0f);
      set.setCircleRadius(1.0f);
      set.setColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
      set.setCircleColor(Color.rgb(240, 99, 99));
      set.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
      set.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
      set.setValueTextSize(1.0f);
      return set;
}

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(int ySum, int uSum, int vSum) {
    img_Y_Avg = ySum;
    img_U_Avg = uSum;
    img_V_Avg = vSum;

    //set value of Y on the text view
    TextView valueOfY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueY);
    valueY = img_Y_Avg;
    valueOfY.setText(Double.toString(img_Y_Avg));

    //set value of U on the text view
    TextView valueOfU = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueU);
    valueU = img_U_Avg;
    valueOfU.setText(Double.toString(img_U_Avg));

    //set value of V on the text view
    TextView valueOfV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.valueV);
    valueV = img_V_Avg;
    valueOfV.setText(Double.toString(img_V_Avg));

    //store value to array list
    ArrayList<Integer> yAverage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    yAverage.add(img_Y_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(yAverage));

    //store u values to array
    ArrayList<Integer> uAverage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    uAverage.add(img_U_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(uAverage));

    //store u values to array
    ArrayList<Integer> vAverage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    vAverage.add(img_V_Avg);
    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(vAverage));

    float start = System.nanoTime();
    int diff = (int) ((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) - start);

    ArrayList<Integer> difference = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    difference.add(diff);

    Log.d("time", String.valueOf(start));


    ArrayList<Integer> getValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < uAverage.size(); i++) {
        //getValues.add(difference.get(i));
        getValues.add(yAverage.get(i));
        getValues.add(uAverage.get(i));
        getValues.add(vAverage.get(i));
    }


    String filename = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'.csv'").format(new Date());

    File directoryDownload = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File logDir = new File (directoryDownload, "bpReader"); //Creates a new folder in DOWNLOAD directory
    logDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(logDir, filename);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
           outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
           //outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           for (int i = 0; i < uAverage.size(); i += 3) {
               //outputStream.write((getValues.get(i) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i + 1) + ",").getBytes());
               outputStream.write((getValues.get(i + 2) + "\n").getBytes());

            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(getValues));


    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            readingRemaining = readingRemaining -1;

            if (readingRemaining > 0){
                plotGraph(img_Y_Avg);
                //plotGraph(img_U_Avg);
                //plotGraph(img_V_Avg);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);

    //Log.d("MyEntryData", String.valueOf(img_Y_Avg +" "+ img_U_Avg+" "+img_V_Avg));

}

private void plotGraph(double graph_data){
    LineData data = bp_graph.getData();
    if (data != null){
        ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        if (set == null){
            set = createSet();
            data.addDataSet(set);
        }

        //add a new value
        int randomDataSetIndex = (int) (Math.random() * data.getDataSetCount());
        float yValue = (float)  graph_data;


        data.addEntry(new Entry(data.getDataSetByIndex(randomDataSetIndex).getEntryCount(), yValue), randomDataSetIndex);

        //notify chart data have changed
        bp_graph.notifyDataSetChanged();

        bp_graph.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(100);

        //scroll to last entry
        bp_graph.moveViewTo(data.getEntryCount() - 7, 50f, YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
    }
}}
```

I am doing the image processing inside the `CameraView` class and then with the help of an interface sending the values to `MainActivity`, where I generate the .csv file and the graph.
How do i get the time difference between each frame(or 2 consecutive y-sum) that is being generated?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

img_Y_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoYSum(data, width, height);
img_U_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoUSum(data, width, height);
img_V_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoVSum(data, width, height);

long finishTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewFrame(img_Y_Avg, img_U_Avg, img_V_Avg,finishTime-startTime);
```

And add this parameter to interface:

```
public interface PreviewReadyCallback {
    void onPreviewFrame(int yAverage, int uAverage, int vAverage, long time);
}
```

Then save it to CSV like other values...

Update:
That was your calculation time. If you want time between frames:
In class:

```
long oldTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and then

```
img_Y_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoYSum(data, width, height);
img_U_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoUSum(data, width, height);
img_V_Avg = ImageProcessing.YUV420SPtoVSum(data, width, height);

long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

mPreviewReadyCallback.onPreviewFrame(img_Y_Avg, img_U_Avg, img_V_Avg,newTime-oldTime);
oldTime=newTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have this and am getting the values in an ArrayList the same way im getting the other values. However, the time values are either 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: nanoTime() is giving some values. But if you look at my code, i have specified 16 fps constant and in my log there are 16 values generated each second. So, to my understanding, if i add all the values for time difference for a specific second  i should get around 1 second. But here im getting around 0.01 seconds.

Comment: i tried long durationInMs = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.convert(timeElapsed, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS); before storing it into array.. still i get values which are way incorrect. Since 16fps, each value should be approximately 62000 microseconds. but i am getting around 150 - 2000 microseconds

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. I actually did this a while ago but there is a problem. On carefully observing the log i found, the consecutive start(i) and stop(i) times have a difference of 0, 1 or 2 milliseconds. The actually difference is between stop(i) and start(i+1)..... stop(i+1) and start(i+2).. and so on. So im passing both start time and end time to the mainAvticity, storing them into two separate values and trying to iterate through them to do something like end(i+1) - start(i) or end(i+1)-end(i)..